# Installation failed: Could not create directory - CentOS 7

Tags: nginx, filesystem

I have spent over 6 hours trying to do the 5-minute installation.  I've searched Google over and over, and have yet to find anything that will actually fix my problem, so hopefully someone here can be of help.

I installed Wordpress (using [these instructions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Detailed_Instructions)).  Installation went as expected.  However, I now cannot install or uninstall any plugins or themes.  My server does not have FTP (and I intend to keep it that way), so I'm using `define('FS_METHOD','direct');` in **functions.php**.

I'm using Nginx on CentOS 7, so I set the owner of `/usr/share/nginx/html` (recursively) to `nginx:nginx`.  That directory is the location of my Wordpress installation.  I have also set my directories to `chmod 755` and files to `chmod 644`, per every reputable resource I could find online.  As far as I can tell, based on what I can find online, those things there should make it work, and yet, the issue persists.

What do I need to do to fix the file permissions?

I know I'm probably going to get marked as duplicate, but I assure you I have attempted every reasonable idea I could find online, both on Google and on this site.  Just for the record:

- Chmod 777 on everything doesn't make it work
- Chown root on everything doesn't make it work
- Yes, I'm using `-R` on my chown and chmod commands
- Yes, I have rebooted my server several times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SELinux was the problem.  Its enforcement was, for lack of a better term, overriding the file permissions and keeping Wordpress from writing to any of the files.

To solve the issue, I did the following:

**Check if SELinux is enabled:**

```
# getenforce
```

If the response is "Enforcing", then SELinux is enabled and it is probably your problem.

Just for good measure, let's go ahead and **ensure that the file permissions are correct**:

```
# cd /path/to/wordpress/
# find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
# find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

In those commands, we navigated to the directory where Wordpress is stored, and then set the file permissions per the Wordpress [File Permissions help article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions).

Before we move on, we need to **lock down all SELinux enforcement for the entire Wordpress directory**.  This ensures that we don't have any stray vulnerabilities:

```
# chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/wordpress/ -R
```

Next, we need to **set SELinux to allow the appropriate write access**:

```
# cd /path/to/wordpress/
# chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t wp-config.php
# chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t wp-content -R
```

Note that we allowed write access (`rw`) to both the wp-config file and the wp-content directory, *recursively*.

Once you have completed all those steps, restart Nginx and visit Wordpress in your browser.  You should now be able to successfully install/remove plugins and themes.

**Note: DO NOT DISABLE SELINUX ALTOGETHER.  Only modify the enforcement as listed above.  Disabling SELinux is a major security vulnerability.**